# C# Windows Forms inner join three tables

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, inner-join

I have a problem with SQL query in C#.

In my database I have tables: *Supplier*, *ApplicationForm,* *SupplierAdress*. I was trying to join these three tables but I got an syntax error with the `inner join`.

Also my method in C# have input parameter *AppFormID*. With that parameter I have to open particular Application Form from database on Windows app.

This is my SQL query:

```
command.CommandText = "select ApplicationForm.Date,ApplicationForm.About,ApplicationForm.Supplier," + 
                      " Supplier.IDSupplier,Supplier.Name,Supplier.Email,Supplier.Phone," +
                      " Supplier.SupplierAdress,SupplierAdress.AdressID,SupplierAdress.Name" +
                      " from ApplicationForm" +
                      " inner join Supplier on ApplicationForm.Supplier=Supplier.IDSupplier" +
                      " inner join SupplierAdress on ApplicationForm.Supplier.SupplierAdress = SupplierAdress .AdressID" +
                      " where ApplicationForm.ApplicatonFormID=" + AppFormID;
```

I hope that someone will help me.

Comment: "SupplierAdress .AdressID" you have an unwanted space before the dot (period)

Comment: Use parameterized queies. The fact that it's a winforms application does not protect you from Sql injection. Parameters do. Also, `ApplicationForm.Supplier.SupplierAdress =SupplierAdress .AdressID` should be `Supplier.SupplierAdress =SupplierAdress.AdressID`

Comment: this problem is not related to `windows` or `forms` is just related to the SQL query written.

Comment: What is the error you're getting

Comment: I don't have white space in my app, this is my mistake in posting question. Previously i try that but also got this error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression
Thank's for advice!

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong `ApplicationForm.Supplier.SupplierAdress`

try this, dunno exact field names:

```
from 
    ApplicationForm 
    inner join Supplier on ApplicationForm.Supplier=Supplier.IDSupplier 
    inner join SupplierAdress on Supplier.IdAdress =SupplierAdress.AdressID
```

Comment: I previously try that but not working. Thanks for suggestion.